# Rvest scraping result is empty list

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I've a simple question: I tried to scrape odds from a webpage but the result is a blank list

```
library(rvest)
url<- 'http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/italy/serie-a-2016-2017/'
html <- read_html(url)
odds <- html_nodes(html, '.table-matches__odds , .colored span')
odds <- html_text(odds)
```

Also I tried to use xpath instead of css selector but I had same result.

```
library(rvest)
url<- 'http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/italy/serie-a-2016-2017/'
html <- read_html(url)
odds <- html_nodes(html, xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ),   concat( " ", "table-matches__odds", " " ))]')
odds <- html_text(odds)
```